# How do I test if device is Bare Metal or VSI in postinstall script

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I have a postinstall script for CentOS, RedHat, Debian, and Ubuntu. How do distinquish if the device is a VSI or a Bare Metal.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use the "user metadata" for both devices to distinguish between each other just setting it with the device name.

You can set the user metadata e.g. for VSI like below example:

Method: POST

```
https://[username]:[apiKey]@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest/[virtualGuestId]/setUserMetadata
```

Body: Json

```
{
    "parameters": [
        [
                   "Virtual Guest"
           ]
      ]
}
```

Reference:

https://softlayer.github.io/reference/services/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest/setUserMetadata/

For the Hardware server it is the same:

Method: POST

```
https://[username]:[apiKey]@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Hardware_Server/[hardwareId]/setUserMetadata
```

Body: Json

```
{
    "parameters": [
        [
               "Hardware Server"
         ]
    ]
}
```

Reference:

https://softlayer.github.io/reference/services/SoftLayer_Hardware_Server/setUserMetadata/

Once the metadata is set, you can use the "getUserMetadata
" method in your "post install script", the following curl command can be execute into the device, it does not required username and apiKey.

```
curl https://api.service.softlayer.com/rest/v3.1/SoftLayer_Resource_Metadata/getUserMetadata
```

Here there is an example about how to configure a storage with a post install script and metadatas, I think this can help you as a reference:

https://softlayer.github.io/article/AutomatingStorage/